# Using X-Sendfile with Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, x-sendfile

I can't seem to find much documentation on X-Sendfile or example code for PHP (there is some rails code).

Anyone used it before and would mind giving a quick snippet of code and a brief description?

Answer (score 31):

X-Sendfile is an HTTP header, so you want something like this:

```
header("X-Sendfile: $filename");
```

Your web server picks it up if correctly configured.  Here's some more details:

http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/

Comment: I followed the tutorial on the link, but when I download file with mod-xsend I get file size Binary File (0 bytes)... What am I doing wrong? UPDATE: have figured it out myself. I needed to add `#enable sending files from parent dirs` -> `XSendFileAllowAbove On` into my .htaccess file, sice my downloads are out of the webroot folder.

Comment: For future readers: XSendFileAllowAbove has been deprecated; use XSendFilePath

Answer (score 3):

If tweaking the web server configuration is not an option, consider PHP's standard [readfile() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). It won't be quite as fast as sendfiling, but it will be more widely compatible. Also note that when doing this, you should also send a Content-Type header at the very least.

Comment: Please note that if you use `readfile()`, you will have no support for resuming or partial downloads (Request-Range) or client caching (i.e., returning a `304 Not modified` when needed) (or you will need to handle all this yourself with PHP code -- there should be some code snippets around that exactly do that).