# Downloading large files reliably in PHP

Tags: php, download

I have a php script on a server to send files to recipents: they get a unique link and then they can download large files. Sometimes there is a problem with the transfer and the file is corrupted or never finishes. I am wondering if there is a better way to send large files

Code:

```
$f = fopen(DOWNLOAD_DIR.$database[$_REQUEST['fid']]['filePath'], 'r');
while(!feof($f)){
    print fgets($f, 1024);
}
fclose($f);
```

I have seen functions such as

```
http_send_file
http_send_data
```

But I am not sure if they will work.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Regards
erwing

Comment: Part of this problem might be solved by supporting `Range` headers, so browsers can pause and resume downloads. Here's a question dealing with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6527829/1469208) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21354337/1469208) SO answers.

Comment: See it here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827768/how-to-download-large-files-with-php/47827769#47827769

Answer (score 18):

Chunking files is the fastest / simplest method in PHP, if you can't or don't want to make use of something a bit more professional like [cURL](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php), [`mod-xsendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) on [Apache](http://durham.net.au/force-download-large-files-with-php/) or some [dedicated script](http://phpsnips.com/579/PHP-download-script-for-Large-File-Downloads#.UwdOiWJ5Nfg).

```
$filename = $filePath.$filename;

$chunksize = 5 * (1024 * 1024); //5 MB (= 5 242 880 bytes) per one chunk of file.

if(file_exists($filename))
{
    set_time_limit(300);

    $size = intval(sprintf("%u", filesize($filename)));

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($filename).'"');

    if($size > $chunksize)
    { 
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb'); 

        while (!feof($handle))
        { 
          print(@fread($handle, $chunksize));

          ob_flush();
          flush();
        } 

        fclose($handle); 
    }
    else readfile($path);

    exit;
}
else echo 'File "'.$filename.'" does not exist!';
```

Ported from [richnetapps.com](http://www.richnetapps.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/) / [NeedBee](http://need-bee.com/b/2011/11/downloading-large-files-in-php/). Tested on 200 MB files, on which `readfile()` died, even with maximum allowed memory limit set to `1G`, that is five times more than downloaded file size.

BTW: I tested this also on files `>2GB`, but PHP only managed to write first `2GB` of file and then broke the connection. File-related functions (fopen, fread, fseek) uses INT, so you ultimately hit the limit of `2GB`. Above mentioned solutions (i.e. `mod-xsendfile`) seems to be the only option in this case.

**EDIT**: *Make yourself **100%** that your file is saved in `utf-8`. If you omit that, downloaded files will be corrupted. This is, because this solutions uses `print` to push chunk of a file to a browser.*

Comment: This is a prefectly working solution, used and tested in many of my projects. So, I assume, that the downvoter, how isn't even able to express in comment, why he/she is downvoting, simply had a bad day or can't even understand this answer. Pity in both cases...

Comment: @user2864740 Maybe it does in your PHP, but not in mine and not in an official one. Tell me, where, exactly where in [`readfile` doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) you see any mention about chunking? Where? There's only a mention about **user-defined** `readfile_chunked` function, which source code looks... **nearly exactly like in above example**. Check, before you state your false claims!

Comment: From the documentation: "Note: *readfile() will **not** present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own*. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with ob_get_level()." This implies that internally readfile is streaming (aka "chunking"); and that the problem with any streamed approach is still the output buffering, if active.

Comment: I wouldn't say, that this description implies or even suggests an internal "chunking" at all! And beside, usng pure `readfile()` on large files, dies on client-side -- browser terminating connection, that takes too long, not on memory issues. If `readfile()` is chinking files, then it most likely does it for just the reading file on server, but it still sends entire file as **one** request response. And this dies on most browsers. Chunking in my solution cause to download file in multiple responses and allows browser to handle downloads of even large files.

Comment: It is only possible to claim '[no] memory issue' when using an approach that takes O(1) memory - and for downloading a file this implies the operation is streaming. Anyway, how does this code cause 'multiple responses'? It is still a *single* HTTP request. If output buffering is disable both approaches will also work the same on the upside as the file read has to be written somewhere (directly to the HTTP response stream).. and thus read somewhere (on the client).

Comment: I suspect that the code that used readfile - that prompted this and similar solutions - failed to correctly invoke [ob_clean_end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) and thus didn't disable the output buffer which would lead to the problems incorrectly attributed to readfile. The proposed code work without ending the output buffer because it explicitly flushes it; but this is nothing against readfile, only improper buffer state configuration.

Comment: When you say your file is saved in utf-8, are you referring to the file being downloaded? If yes, how do I know my file is in utf-8?

Comment: Can this also be used for zip files? It doesn't seem to work

Comment: @GellieAnn You're referring to 7 years old answer. I am no longer PHP developer. The `    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` and `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');` suggests pure binary connection though, so in theory there should be absolutely no problem in downloading ZIP files this way. But I cannot verify that in practice. Also note that ZIP file are not meant to be larger than 2 GB and PHP's library may not be able to process larger files (many ZIP clients are not able to; other uses some weird tricks to handle ZIP files that large). Maybe here is the problem.

Comment: @GellieAnn When talking about UTF-8 encoding I was most likely talking about .php file itself (with above code) those seven years ago. Not about files that you're going to download this way. Downloaded files were meant to be binary. Binary files cannot be encoded with text encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: @trejder My zip file is less than 1GB so there might be something else. I might look at it again sometime but for now I ended up not zipping the files. Your 7 year old code still works. Thanks! Also thank you for answering my questions, appreciate it.

Answer (score 12):

If you are sending truly large files and worried about the impact this will have, you could use the x-sendfile header.

From the SOQ [using-xsendfile-with-apache-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80186/using-xsendfile-with-apache-php), an howto [blog.adaniels.nl : how-i-php-x-sendfile/](https://web.archive.org/web/20171205120512/http://blog.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/)

Comment: There is a ["**large file download**" PHP script here](http://phpsnips.com/579/PHP-download-script-for-Large-File-Downloads) that can handle around **2GB** of many file types like exe, mp3, mp4, pdf etc. This script is worth for downloading smaller to medium file sizes via PHP script. It also describes about **X-sendfile** for really massive file downloads like more than 5GB. Check out the link.

Comment: @webblover - your link is dead. can you repost?

Comment: @Ben  sorry for that. 'phpsnips' website had removed that snippet. You may download it from Github directly: https://github.com/saleemkce/downloadable/blob/master/download.php

Comment: "**Large File download**" script **REPOSTED** just above here.

Answer (score 8):

Best solution would be to rely on lighty or apache, but if in PHP, I would use [PEAR's HTTP_Download](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.php) (no need to reinvent the wheel etc.), has some nice features, like:

- Basic throttling mechanism
- Ranges (partial downloads and resuming)

See [intro/usage docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.intro.php).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to HTTP_Download, exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly when downloading CD images.

Comment: I had to fix a couple deprecated reference errors and non-static method usage, but in 5 minutes i got it up and running, so it's nothing too hard. It may be because i have an outdated pear library, but it's worth to notice.

Comment: This didn't age very well. HTTP_Download is obsolete in 2020 and cannot even be ran in php7 because it uses `&new` object instance creation method which gives an error in PHP 7. I wasted a lot of time to get pear working and install the HTTP_Download extension, just to see the package is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

We've been using this in a couple of projects and it works quite fine so far:

```
/**
 * Copy a file's content to php://output.
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return void
 */
protected function _output($filename)
{
    $filesize = filesize($filename);

    $chunksize = 4096;
    if($filesize > $chunksize)
    {
        $srcStream = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        $dstStream = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

        $offset = 0;
        while(!feof($srcStream)) {
            $offset += stream_copy_to_stream($srcStream, $dstStream, $chunksize, $offset);
        }

        fclose($dstStream);
        fclose($srcStream);   
    }
    else 
    {
        // stream_copy_to_stream behaves() strange when filesize > chunksize.
        // Seems to never hit the EOF.
        // On the other handside file_get_contents() is not scalable. 
        // Therefore we only use file_get_contents() on small files.
        echo file_get_contents($filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted this, but all it seemed to do was output text to the screen. How do I turn this into a file to download?

Comment: This is a different topic. You have to set the appropriate content headers: Content-Type, Content-Length and probably Content-Disposition.

Comment: Wouldn't 4KB chunks be inefficient? I would at least do 0.5MB

Answer (score 4):

For downloading files the easiest way I can think of would be to put the file in a temporary location and give them a unique URL that they can download via regular HTTP.

As part generating these links you could also remove files that were more than X hours old.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it requires additional use of crons or such to remove the old files, and that adds another layer of complexity and another point of failure to the system, but I'm not going to vote it down because it is a valid answer.

Comment: @Unkwntech - no need for cron, as mentioned while generating new files you can also discard older ones. Lots of websites perform cron-like tasks as part of another call.

Comment: @Andrew Grant, you are correct that it could be done without a CRON, but I still feel that it adds an extra point of failure, whereas with my answer I don't think that it is adding an extra failure point.

Comment: But what you get out of it is punting the complexity of the actual HTTP communication to the server, where it belongs (things like expire headers, range downloads, caching, etc.). *I* would rather clean up a few files with a script than reimplement HTTP in my application.

Comment: I agree with Will. Browsers these days have sophisticated downloaders that can pause and resume downloads using built-in features of http.

Answer (score 3):

Create a symbolic link to the actual file and make the download link point at the symbolic link.  Then, when the user clicks on the DL link, they'll get a file download from the real file but named from the symbolic link.  It takes milliseconds to create the symbolic link and is better than trying to copy the file to a new name and download from there.

For example:

```
<?php

// validation code here

$realFile = "Hidden_Zip_File.zip";
$id = "UserID1234";

if ($_COOKIE['authvalid'] == "true") {
    $newFile = sprintf("myzipfile_%s.zip", $id); //creates: myzipfile_UserID1234.zip

    system(sprintf('ln -s %s %s', $realFile, $newFile), $retval);

    if ($retval != 0) {
        die("Error getting download file.");
    }

    $dlLink = "/downloads/hiddenfiles/".$newFile;
}

// rest of code

?>

<a href="<?php echo $dlLink; ?>Download File</a>
```

That's what I did because Go Daddy kills the script from running after 2 minutes 30 seconds or so....this prevents that problem and hides the actual file.

You can then setup a CRON job to delete the symbolic links at regular intervals....

This whole process will then send the file to the browser and it doesn't matter how long it runs since it's not a script.

Answer (score 1):

When I have done this in the past I've used this:

```
set_time_limit(0); //Set the execution time to infinite.
header('Content-Type: application/exe'); //This was for a LARGE exe (680MB) so the content type was application/exe
readfile($fileName); //readfile will stream the file.
```

These 3 lines of code will do all the work of the download [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) will stream the entire file specified to the client, and be sure to set an infinite time limit else you may be running out of time before the file is finished streaming.

Comment: Of course, if this isn't an exe, the mime type should be different.

Comment: Also, never-ever-ever combine set_time_limit(0) with ignore_user_abort()  or the script could be running forever.

Comment: Very true, unless of course you want the script to continue running after the user dies.

Comment: That would leave evidence that you killed the user.  Not exactly a good idea.

Comment: readfile() still uses a lot of memory -- big files and high traffic will exhaust php with this method

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK FOR large files. The question is specifically about LARGE files. Down vote.

Comment: DOES NOT WORK FOR LARGE FILES! Downwote if you can.
Try solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031301/php-readfile-not-working-for-me-and-i-dont-know-why

Comment: As other already mentioned, this is of course not true. The `readfile` function does not stream anything. It just tries to read entire file into memory and throw whole into browser. This will die on anything larger than 100 MB. And it will die "brutally", i.e. no error message, only your user downloads HTML page with error about exhausting memory, instead of real file. For real streaming of large files you have to implement something more sophisticated than these three lines. For example, file chunking. See [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21936954/1469208) below.

Comment: @trejder Incorrect; readfile does not read everything into memory. The file contents might end up in the output buffer cache, if the cache is not properly disabled - but this is not related to readfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lighttpd as a webserver, an alternative for secure downloads would be to use [ModSecDownload](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModSecDownload). It needs server configuration but you'll let the webserver handle the download itself instead of the PHP script.

Generating the download URL would look like that (taken from the documentation) and it could of course be only generated for authorized users:

```
<?php

  $secret = "verysecret";
  $uri_prefix = "/dl/";

  # filename
  # please note file name starts with "/" 
  $f = "/secret-file.txt";

  # current timestamp
  $t = time();

  $t_hex = sprintf("%08x", $t);
  $m = md5($secret.$f.$t_hex);

  # generate link
  printf('<a href="%s%s/%s%s">%s</a>',
         $uri_prefix, $m, $t_hex, $f, $f);
?>
```

Of course, depending on the size of the files, using `readfile()` such as proposed by [Unkwntech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/sending-large-files-reliably-in-php/597184#597184) is excellent. And using xsendfile as proposed by [garrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/sending-large-files-reliably-in-php/597195#597195) is another good idea also supported by Apache.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Content-length:".filesize($filename));
header('Content-Type: application/zip'); // ZIP file
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloadpackage.zip"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
ob_end_clean();
readfile($filename);
exit();
```

Comment: Will not work for large files. Would run out of memory within seconds.

Comment: @Scottymeuk Why? Please provide a resource.

Comment: This is all you need to do. Really. Not sure why this is not accepted. The "key" is to use ob_end_clean (which could be wrapped in an ob_get_level) to *disable* the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea for large files. If the thread for your download script runs until the user has finished the download, and you're running something like Apache, just 50 or more concurrent downloads could crash your server, because Apache isn't designed to run large numbers of long-running threads at the same time. Of course I might be wrong, if the apache thread somehow terminates and the download sits in a buffer somewhere whilst the download progresses.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following snippet found in the comments of the php manual entry for readfile:

```
function _readfileChunked($filename, $retbytes=true) {
    $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: Another unnecessary implementation. See my comments on  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21936954/2864740 for why.

Comment: That is incorrect. I know it by experience. Using ob_end_clean() as you state in that coments didn't solve the problem for me, while the chunked solution did. Key is that readfile doesn't allow files close to or larger than the PHP memory limit to be downloaded. This is a simple solution that works, and as such, you shouldn't downrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem,
my problem solved by adding this before starting session
session_cache_limiter('none');

Answer (score 0):

This is tested on files of a size 200+ MB on a server that has 256MB memory limit.

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
set_time_limit(0);
$file = @fopen($filePath, "rb");
while(!feof($file)) {
  print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```