# How can I download a Zip file from Localhost in php?

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to download a zip file from my localhost.The file is downloading but gives an error message "invalid" when I open it.
I am using the following code:-

```
 $filename = "markers.zip";  
`if(file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename)){  
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename));  
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");  
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");  
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");  
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));  
        flush();  
        $fp = fopen($filename, "r");  
        while (!feof($fp))  
        {  
            echo fread($fp, 65536);  
            flush();  
        }  
        fclose($fp);  
        exit;  
    }`
```

Comment: You have three content type headers there, all of them wrong. The media type for zip files is `application/zip`

Comment: And why all the `flush()` and the loop?  Just use `readfile()`.

Comment: The example at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php shows how to do a download. Just use the right `Content-Type` and you should be all set.

Comment: Have a look at the solution provided in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681844/php-zip-file-download

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried with 'application/zip' but still the same.

Comment: Check out this: [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007797/alternative-way-to-hide-download-link/15007917#15007917)

Comment: if you have some HTML or print or echo before header() then move them under your download function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = "file.zip";
header('Content-type: application/x-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
readfile($file);
?>
```