# Increase the limit of file download size in Document management system

Tags: php, document-management

I am using the Document Management System which is created on KnowledgeTree frame work. My goal is to Download the stored files. When the files are downloaded the contents are limited to certain mb and the rest is ignored. Which results in downloading in parts. How can I increase the file download limit so that the whole file can be downloaded in a single attempt.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To download large files from server, I have changed the below settings in php.ini file:

```
Upload_max_filesize  - 1500 M
Max_input_time  - 1000
Memory_limit    - 640M
Max_execution_time -  1800
Post_max_size - 2000 M
```

Now, I am able to upload and download 175MB video on server.
Since, I have the dedicated server. So, making these changes were easy.

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527811/how-to-download-large-files-through-php-script)

Comment: it's my pleasure . . .!! :)