# File with large size does not download with php

Tags: php, download

i have the following script for file download.

```
function download(){
        $this->file = $this->getFile();
        if($this->filesize <= 0 || $this->filesize == null){
            echo $this->filesize;
        } else {
           set_time_limit(0);

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-type:'.$this->contenttype);
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$this->filename.'.'.$this->extension);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            ob_end_clean();
            readfile('/upload/'.$this->fileUid.'.'.$this->extension);
        }

        die();
    }
```

when i try to download file with small size (in Kbs) file(s) download successfully, but if file size is large i.e greate than 1MB, then file does not downloads properly, the downloaded files size is in Kbs, and files does not open either. Can any one kindly help me in this regards, i tried `ob_end_clean()` but did not work. Kindly help me. 
Regards,

Comment: If you open the downloaded file in a text editor, is there any error message on the last line?

Comment: yes, <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(/home/totalrec/upload/c924b6aa211faf2706e89abd3aaeea29.pdf) [<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/totalrec/public_html/test1/classes/file.class.php</b> on line <b>418</b><br />
is the content of file.

Comment: Then that's problem solved I think, lol :)

Comment: but the file is there, i can see it in upload folder

Comment: Are you sure? You said the script works for smaller files, but not large ones, there is no other variable.

Answer (score 2):

As I worked out in your question comments, the file does not exist on the server. So the real problem is the upload script.

You should read [**Common Pitfalls Of File Upload**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) My guess is `upload_max_filesize`, although it could be any of these pitfalls, depends on the server setup.

Comment: so does it mean that upload script is not working for large files? as small files are working fine.

Comment: this is my upload script [
move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name, "/home/totalrec/upload/" . $this->fileUid.'.'.$this->ext);]

Comment: @Shahzeb, you could make use of this **PHP download script**. Works for massively large files with great MIME support. [**Large File Download**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176942/using-php-to-download-files-not-working-on-large-files/21354337#21354337)  I checked out this by downloading about 2GB file. It works.