# Redirect PHP to download .dat file automatically

Tags: php, redirect, download

How is it possible to automically redirect thankyou.php page to download ".DAT" file which is available at different directory.

File Dir = http://domain.com/storage/file.dat
While thankyou.php is available at root http://domain.com/thankyou.php

Thanks for everyone answering my question.

Following @bruno-fidelis which I thank alot I'm getting the below error message for the file downloaded. I mean when the file is downloaded and open it I get this error message

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Thank You</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(http://domain.com/path/to/file/filename.dat): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
in <b>/home/user/public_html/dir/success.php</b> on line <b>159</b><br />
```

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for http://domain.com/path/to/file/filename.dat in **/home/user/public_html/dir/success.php** on line **160**

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: I tried this one but it's not working

Comment: Post your code that is not working!

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/3294262) you can find detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Set header in your PHP file to download file automatically.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($File) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($File));
header("Connection: close");
```

To download larger file size from server, change the below settings in php.ini file:

```
Upload_max_filesize  - 1500 M
Max_input_time  - 1000
Memory_limit    - 640M
Max_execution_time -  1800
Post_max_size - 2000 M
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527811/how-to-download-large-files-through-php-script) also.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the share but it's not downloading the file in it's complete size :)

Comment: Thanks Ravi I think I got thos info well set however I'll double check

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a script setting the headers to the file. Example.

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('path/to/file.dat');
$size = filesize('path/to/file.dat');
$quotedFileName = '"'. basename('path/to/file.dat') .'"';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quotedFileName);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
flush();
echo $file;
exit();
```

I suggest you read about [http headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). Let me know if it works ;)

Comment: thanks for share it helps sure but still facing the size issue.

Comment: what kind of size issue ? if the file is to large you'll have to configure php.ini file to accept larger post size [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176942/using-php-to-download-files-not-working-on-large-files)

Comment: The file size ranges between 1MB till 4MB

Comment: @WiTonNope i've added flush() after the headers, give it a try. Just of curiosity, why you say it's a size issue ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thanks for updating the code. Unfortunately it didn't work also. I am saying it's size issue because the file is 1.74MB and when downloading it I get only 776B that's even less the half of the real size.

Comment: You could try using readfile($file); instead of file_get_contents there's an example on php [documentation](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#48683)

Comment: I think I found the reason if I'm correct, the file link is auto-generated and not static everytime so this is the code I am using  `$file = file_get_contents(''.$url.'/used/'.$products.'/'.$orderid.'.dat'); ` I think this is wrong maybe

Comment: Only one way to find out, in that case you should check if the file_exists();

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the info it turns to be that file_get_contents not reading the dir correctly when I used readfile it worked however I had to override php.ini of the server as readfile() was disabled by server do you think it's risky to open allow_fopen?

Comment: It is risky to allow_fopen because you can potentially allow for attackers inject code on your application. That been said, if you need to fetch a remote file safely, an alternative is to use php function curl(); witch does not require allow_fopen.

Comment: exactly this is what I know thus I've blocked allow_fopen from the server and opened it into the account side however I'll try curl as you said I missed that part sorry. One thing is the file isn't being read in the right way still I'll update my question with error please check it.