# PHP exports an empty excel file

Tags: php, excel

I hope somebody can help me with this.

I want to export a html table in excel, I used PHP using this code:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
  header("Content-Disposition: filename=".$_POST['filename']);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  echo $_POST['datos_a_enviar'];
?>
```

The PHP receives a string from another page, and I test it and actually receive the string correctly , however when exporting to Excel, the file you exported is completely empty , even the weight of the file in disk is 0. This only happens when there are many records , because with few records, the excels have the data.

When I was testing in localhost, the excel exports all the data, but when I uploaded to the server, that happens, with a lot of regs, the file is empty.

Thanks for the help, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean " a lot of reg "? Do you get any kind of error displayed.

Comment: No errors displayed. Only the empty file.  With a lot of records, it's about 700

Comment: I think it is a duplicate from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176942/using-php-to-download-files-not-working-on-large-files)

Answer (score 0):

You must check the server limitation for the POST size.
If you're working with PHP under Linux or similar, you can control these using .htaccess, like so:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

PHP has other limits on script time, so if you say it takes lots of regs, maybe it is that:

Try tweaking the [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) and [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) variables in `php.ini`. If you don't have access to `php.ini`, try the [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and/or [`ini_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) functions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have in my .htaccess this: `php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value max_execution_time 10000
php_value max_input_time 10000`                                                                                        And, in the server the value for post_max_size is 200M

Comment: Do you know what size is the file you want to generate?

Comment: Yes, it´s around 1M...2M is the biggest