# Php Tracking Large File Download Count

Tags: php

I have a php site am trying to track number of times my downloads get hit using the following code:

```
                //update download count
                update_attachment_counter($attachment);

                // We'll be outputting a PDF
                header ( 'Content-Type: application/pdf' );
                header ( 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="fileName.pdf"');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($attachment));
                readfile ( $attachment );
                die ();
```

I am seeing my counters go up multiple times per download. My attachments are anywhere from 2 to 30MB in size. Does it make since that I am seeing multiple requests per download? How do I only track each download once?

Comment: possibly the download is having to be restarted by the user due to network failure OR there is an error in update_attachment_counter (the code to which you didn't post)

Comment: update_attachment_counter does a ++ on a database value. Nothing exciting and works great if I die immediately following it. I did not feel like posting my schema, etc :)

Comment: how about changing  update_attachment_counter to log date, ip,file then it would be easer to debug. still easy to do a querry for the count

Comment: I know what the counter should be because I'm the only person who can hit it right now, so I don't have to worry about multiple people trying to download things simultaneously yet. Do you think the browser might be restarting the download due to a timeout or something?

Comment: Are you using any browser extensions that might be doing multi-segment downloads?

Comment: HEAD requests before the actual downloads or parallel downloads.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I don't think so. I am currently testing with chrome so unless it is doing it automatically?

Comment: If your connection is HTTP you might be able to tell using fiddler2 if you can spot multiple simultaneous requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the large file size, I am getting partial download requests. By checking for HTTP_RANGE I was able to determine if it was the original request or the partial request:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
  .... update counter
}
```

See [using php to download files, not working on large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176942/using-php-to-download-files-not-working-on-large-files)