# How to detect X-Accel-Redirect (Nginx) / X-Sendfile (Apache) support in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, memory, nginx, large-files

### About Application

I am working on an e-commerce application in PHP. To keep URL's secure, product download links are kept behind PHP. There is a file, say download.php, which accepts few parameter via GET and verifies them against a database. If all goes well, it serves file using readfile() function in PHP.

### About Problem

Now problem comes when file to be passed to readfile() is larger than memory limit set in php.ini
As this application will be used by many users on shared-hosting we cannot relay on altering php.ini settings.

In our effort to find workarounds, I first thought we can go for fread() calls in while loop but it seems that will impose problems as well as highlighted here [Downloading large files reliably in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/sending-large-files-reliably-in-php)

**So my best option is to detect/check if server supports X-Accel-Redirect (in case of Nginx) / X-Sendfile (in case of Apache)**

If server supports X-Accel-Redirect / X-Sendfile, I can use them and in else block I can make system admin aware about memory limit enforced by php.ini

Ideally, I want to use server side support like X-Accel-Redirect / X-Sendfile wherever possible, and if that doesn't work - I would like to have a fallback code to read files without readfile().

I am not yet sure as how readfile() and fread() in while loop are different but seems while loop will create problem, again, as suggested in [Downloading large files reliably in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/sending-large-files-reliably-in-php)

Hope to get some help, suggestions, codes, guidance.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To detect if the mod_xsendfile apache module installed, you can try this code:

```
if function_exists('apache_get_modules') 
      && in_array('mod_xsendfile', apache_get_modules()) { 
  header("X-Sendfile"); 
}
```

But this code just check if the module installed only, that can cause errors if it's installed but configured wrongly

another possible way to do this to setup server-wide variable through Apache's .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
  <Files *.php>
    XSendFile On
    XSendFileAllowAbove On
    SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

and check it form php code:

```
if ($_SERVER['MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED']) {
  Header(...)
}
```

The common idea is the same for nginx - just pass the value of status variable to backend via HTTP-header or CGI/FastCGI variable.

Comment: Thanks for help. Will above code work in both cases - when php is used as Apache'e mod_php OR fastcgi/fcgi?

Comment: Also, I guess on Nginx, support for X-Accel-Redirect is part of core, so all I need is to detect if (webserver == "nginx") somehow! Right?

Comment: By the way above code snippet helped a lot. So thanks for it. :-)

Comment: The first one code snippet works for mod_php only, but the second one works for both mod_php and CGI/FastCGI mode.

Comment: About nginx - looks like you're right, but your cgi/fastcgi tier don't know anything about the fornt-end server software unlike you'll inform it (using CGI variable or HTTP-header)

Answer (score 5):

`readfile` does not take up a large amount of memory. It opens the file, reads a small portion, writes that portion to the browser and then reuses the memory for the next read. It's the same as using `fread+echo` in a while loop. You will not be constrained by memory-limits, but you will be limited by `max_execution_time` and such.

If you want to use `X-Accel-Redirect` support (or similar) provided by your web server, send a header like this (for Nginx):

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /path/to/file');
```

Your application cannot know if the server supports this. You will need to provide a configuration option so the admin/installer of your software can provide such information manually.

Comment: Thanks for insights into readfile. 
If readfile() works in small memory, why it threw "out of memory" error when we opened large files. Also same error disappeared as soon as we changed php.ini settings. Also readfile() was my last line so I am sure after readfile, my application isn't processing data further.

Comment: One more - if I write `header('X-Accel-Redirect: /path/to/file');` and underlaying server is not configured properly, what will happen? Will the header() call go ignored? Will I get some error message?

Comment: rahul286, someone explains possible memory problems in the comments on http://php.net/readfile as this: "it's because you have output buffering on. Just turn off output buffering immediately before the call to Readfile(). Use something like ob_end_flush()."

Comment: Also, if your web server doesn't support X-Accel-Redirect (or similar) the header will be sent to the web browser, which will ignore it. You won't get any error message.

Comment: Emil, I noticed output_buffering issues. But as my codes are packages as wordpress plugin, and I haven't initiated output buffering, I choose to go ahead with my while loop with flush() calls inside loop. It worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could set an environment variable on the server that controls the correct server header name (probably setup by ops team or whoever is responsible for scripting / defining server environment). This would lend itself to any stack supporting Header based file serving because the people in control of that stack are then enabled to make decisions, whilst you just read in from the environment the header.

```
<?php

/**
 * Method to delegate sending file to webserver
 *
 * Uses environment variable `SERVER_ACCEL_HEADER` to define the specific
 * server header to use to send files from server layer rather than 
 * application layer
 *
 * @param  string $path path to file that should exist
 * @param  bool $die if script should terminate after setting header
 * @return void returns nothing
 */
function sendPathAccel($path, $die=true) {
    $accelHeader = getenv('SERVER_ACCEL_HEADER');
    header("{$accelHeader}: {$path}");
    if($die) { die(); }
}
```

**Warning:** It should be noted that this is not a novice move, so be careful. A Lot could go wrong using this if the people in charge of the server environment do not setup it probably won't work or may cause errors, but it's simple, fast and I can't think of a reason to change it.