# Handle very large http download

Tags: file-transfer

We have a site that offers very large files for download to clients. These files can be from 2GB up to about 14GB. What is the best way to handle download of these files? The site is written in php and the link is provided with `download.php?hash=[somehash]`.

Are there any programs that works great for very large files sent over http? Or should we look at a way to do this with torrent-files or something else?

This is 100 % legal for the septics out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go for a http-downloadclient and configured our Linux-server to handle http-download resume.

I recommend this to everyone who reads this.

Note that this is based on HUGE downloads, like 10GB >

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with php, but you should support continueing of paused download by supporting the byte-range header

have a look at this page: http://www.coneural.org/florian/papers/04_byteserving.php

Edit: also have a look at this question: [Downloading large files reliably in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/sending-large-files-reliably-in-php)