# how to attachment big file in mail with php?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

i attach big file about 0.5 to 1 mb in mail using php (mime.php)

i attach file and send mail, but in mailbox, file name is unknow and also not display bodytext
. so please me .

how to upload big file in mail with php (LAMP)?

Comment: Without sharing the code it's not esay to answer your question. Additionally it would be helpful to know the following: What makes you believe that your code should work at all?

Comment: i make one corn for weekly MySQL backup and i use system command in php , and make one sql file and then user "gzip" command for make ".gz" file and this attach with my email . this zip file size will be 5mb then attach file but this file is unknow, so not get this file ... please help  me

Answer (score 1):

Attaching large files is rarely a necessity. Perhaps you could store it on server and generate a download link, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007260/1324707)?