# What is the best method to serve download files via a download link?

Tags: php, curl, download, fopen, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending large files reliably in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/sending-large-files-reliably-in-php)

I will be distributing a PHP script which enables people to provide downloadable products to their clients from their server via a masked URL (don't want to give away the location on the server). Some files may be pretty large, so I need to make sure I use a method which is capable of handling larger files.

I am familiar with how to utilize each of the following download methods, I am just asking which would be the best to use (most efficient, reliable, universally supported, etc.):

Streaming fopen

Streaming cURL

file_get_contents

cURL

Comment: I'm not sure why you need any of those functions to serve a download?  Can you explain better?

Comment: None of those you've listed. There is `readfile` and actually better is to delegate the job for serving back to the webserver, e.g. `X-Sendfile`.

Comment: Its a large script with a lot of functionality, without explaining everything about it, I just need to know the best way for the script to serve a large download.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally best to let the webserver handle sending static files.

Use x-sendfile for [apache](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), [lighttpd](http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2006/07/02/x-sendfile) or [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile). You can use php for auth, send the `X-Sendfile` header, the script will terminate, and the web server will handle the sending of the file. The end user will never know where the file is on the server.