# Binary-safe function for sending chunks of files in PHP

Tags: php, download, binaryfiles, chunking

I've crafted [my own version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936954/1469208) of simple solution, for sending large files in PHP. It uses file chunks. This solution is proted from various sources and I copy-pasted following code to implement "chunking":

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb'); 

while (!feof($handle))
{ 
    print(@fread($handle, $chunksize));

    ob_flush();
    flush();
} 

fclose($handle);
```

Since it uses `print` to send each chunk to the browser, it is very sensitive to character encoding, in which PHP script is encoded. For example, I noticed, that when script is saved in `ANSI`, downloaded files are corrupted. Only, if I save & upload script encoded in `utf-8`, file are fine.

Is there a better function, than `print` to do the same (send piece of file to browser), that would be independend of script file encoding -- because, for example, would force binary transfer to browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small files you should use [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), that makes all for you to send a file to the client. For really big files these function probably don't work due to [memory problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990503/readfile-reads-0-bytes-from-large-file/).

Also there is a function [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get all file content into a variable if you require to process it before send. Like `readfile` is recommended only for "small" files. "small" depends on the memory allowed to run a PHP process (`memory_limit` parameter in php.ini). Usually servers set it from 8M to 128M and by default is 16MB.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, it does not answer my question, as all functions mentioned by you also output file as string. BTW: you should format your answers using Markdown, to make them more readable. First of all, use links. So: write: `[file_get_contents](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)`, instead of: `file_get_contents http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php`, because in your form, entire link is shown, what breaks text flow and formatting. Also, link to English, not Spanish version of pages.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I take in consideration for future answers.