# Downloading large "private" files using PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, download

I store private files on the server (Centos/Apache/PHP) which an authorized user can download using a webbrowser (determining whether the user is authorized is covered elsewhere, and is not part of the question).

I use the following script to download the file.  It works perfect for small files, however, it doesn't work when the file is large (~80MB).  For these, the downloaded file is zero bytes, and Adobe says it is either non-supported type or damaged due to non-encoded email.  I've confirmed that the file on the server is okay, so the problem is not caused by my upload script.

What could cause this problem and how is it fixed?

Also, is there a better way to restrict downloading files?  My concern is potentially my above approach places excessive work on the server/PHP.  Putting an Apache password on the directory and requiring the user to enter it is not a viable solution.  Don't know if something else exists, but thought I'd ask.

Thank you

```
/* Given: $file='/var/www/private/filename'
          $file_name='xx.pdf'
*/
public function dl_file($file,$file_name)
{
    //First, see if the file exists
    if (!is_file($file)) { die('Document does not exist'); }

    //All this function does is get the appropriate mime type    
    $fileInfo=library::getFileInfo(library::getExt($file_name));

    syslog(LOG_INFO,'Content-Type: '.$fileInfo['mime'].' Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'" Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    //Begin writing headers
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

    //Use the switch-generated Content-Type
    header('Content-Type: '.$fileInfo['mime']);

    //Force the download
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"' );
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
}
```

Output from above syslog:

```
Jun  1 09:24:15 devserver httpd: Content-Type: application/pdf Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xx.pdf" Content-Length: 86396350
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three reasons, I think , for this:

- your script exceed the maximum duration for its execution
- the speed of intenet, in the person who downloaded the file is too
  slow. So your script will exceed the maximum duration for its
  execution , as long as the user has not yet finished download the
  file
- the speed of your server is slow, and in this case no great thing
  to do

a remedy for your problem
try to use the function: set_time_limit ()

```
**`set_time_limit (int $ seconds ) ;`**
```

eg set_limit_time tried ( 120 ) ;
will allow the user to download the file for less than 120 seconds

you must calculate how long you need to download the file, relative to the speed of the internet to your customers, and the speed of your server
add how long the script needs to execute

and this will be the time that you must give to the set_limit_time () function

I hope this has help

more info here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

for more security use mod_xsendfile which is an apache module

mod_xsendfile is a small Apache2 module that processes X-SENDFILE headers registered by the original output handler.

If it encounters the presence of such header it will discard all output and send the file specified by that header instead using Apache internals including all optimizations like caching-headers and sendfile or mmap if configured.

It is useful for processing script-output of e.g. php, perl or any cgi.

Useful?

Yep, it is useful.

```
Some applications require checking for special privileges.
Other have to lookup values first (e.g.. from a DB) in order to correctly process a download request.
Or store values (download-counters come into mind).
etc.
```

Benefits

```
Uses apache internals
Optimal delivery through sendfile and mmap (if available).
Sets correct cache headers such as Etag and If-Modified-Since as if the file was statically served.
Processes cache headers such as If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since.
Support for ranges.
```

visit this link https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I've already modified set_time_limit, and it is not the issue.  I no very little about mod_xsendfile, and will give it a try.

Comment: it it's not the issue then look at the max ram used by the script there is a max size for that too

Comment: Do you mean `memory_limit=128M`?  I bumped it up to 1024M, but no difference.

Comment: Increasing memory_limit seems to work.  Still interested if I would be better off not going through PHP and using symbolic links, but the immediate problem is solved.  Thanks for your help

Comment: i tink better solution is using buffers , i forgot about the the firt time but here is an example of code : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6914978/3388314

Comment: try this too i think it is a better solution : if you use fopen and fread instead of readfile, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer why large files are downloading as zero size, but perhaps I have an alternative which was heavily inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126882/1032531.

First, I will create a directory in the public HTML space called "private".

I will put links in my pages HTML which represents the files to be downloaded which points to a publicly accessible PHP file, and includes the file name in the URL.

Upon being accessed, I will delete all files in the private directory which are older than 1 second.

Then, I will GET the filename and verify that the user is authorized to download the file.

If authorized, I will create a symbolic link located in the private directory which points to the file in question, and redirect the to that symbolic link.

Seem reasonable?

A flaw in my approach is the files will be publicly accessible in the private directory.  I could use a random name, however, I wish the file to be downloaded with the real name for authorized users.  Any suggestions?