# Using original downloadable products URL with Magento instead the custom link

Tags: magento, download, product

I uploaded 4GB full DVD files and placed it inside downloadable product --> URL. The problem is Magento automaticlly creats a custom download link. Instead of downloading directly from the server it uses php to handel the download. For that I need a huge memory limit in php.ini (at least 5 GB) I want the user to get the original full URL so I won't have to use space for every download. how can I do that?

Comment: You realize that your product will then no longer be protected?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the proper tools for proper tasks. If you wan't to pipe the download directly and verify if the user has rights to download the file use x-sendfile mod for apache (or your web server)

https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

[Using X-Sendfile with Apache/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80186/using-x-sendfile-with-apache-php)

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/

you will need to override the downloadable class that sets the headers for download to use proper headers and paths then it will work without consuming huge amounts of memory.

Comment: I don't need that, i don't care about the files because most of my customers won't steal from me. I want Magento to use the URL and not the custom URL can I do that?

Comment: yes you can approach is the same, overwrite the block that gives you the link

Comment: Hi Anton and thank you again. Can you please tell me how to overwrite the block?