# Symfony2 - Force file download

Tags: php, symfony, header, download

I'm trying to download a file when a user clicks on download link.

In Controller:

```
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/octect-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($filename));

    return $response;
```

This is opening the dialog box to save the file, but it says the file is 0 bytes.
And changing it to:

```
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/octect-stream');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($filename));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->setContent(readfile($filename));

        return $response;
```

I get a bunch of weird characters instead of the file download dialog box.

Finally, switching the "setContent" line to:

```
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));
```

It returns a PHP error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size...

Any clues on how to achieve this?
I've done it before in PHP (wihtout MVC), but I don't know what can be missing to do it through Symfony2...

Maybe the solution is setting the memory_limit in PHP.INI, but I guess it´s not the best practice...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I finally solved this without X-SendFile (which is probably the best practice). Anyway, for those who can't get X-Sendfile apache module to work (shared hosting), here's a solution:

```
// Generate response
$response = new Response();

// Set headers
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));

// Send headers before outputting anything
$response->sendHeaders();

$response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));

return $response;
```

Comment: This won't work on Chrome. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834828/chrome-adds-attachment-to-downloaded-file

Comment: I got it working on Chrome by removing the sendHeaders() line.

Comment: The last line is wrong: it appends the file length to the response. (readfiles sends the file content to the output buffer and returns the file length, which is also sent to user through the response)

Comment: I've updated the last line, reviewers can go ahead and confirm the fix.

Comment: I think `return $response;` is missing at the end of your code.

Comment: See "The most comfortable solution is" below

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 92):

The most comfortable solution is

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

$response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);
$response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT);

return $response;
```

Comment: I agree to this one. Regarding the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I've updated the answer to include the import of the ResponseHeaderBag class.

Comment: It's the first time I can download a file in less than 584 lines of code! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't use PHP for downloading files because it's a task for an Apache or Nginx server. Best option is to use X-Accel-Redirect (in case of Nginx) / X-Sendfile (in case of Apache) headers for file downloading.

Following action snippet can be used with configured Nginx to download files from Symfony2:

```
return new Response('', 200, array('X-Accel-Redirect' => $filename));
```

**UPD1:** Code for apache with configured mod_xsendfile:

```
return new Response('', 200, array(
    'X-Sendfile'          => $filename,
    'Content-type'        => 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename))
);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your reply!
Do you know how to manage with X-Sendfile?

Comment: `X-Sendfile` is a typical header and works like `X-Accel-Redirect`. Linked answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80186/using-x-sendfile-with-apache-php

Answer (score 9):

Don't know if it can help but it's `application/octet-stream` not `application/octect-stream`

Answer (score 9):

As of Symfony 3.2 you can use the [file() controller helper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#file-helper) which is a shortcut for creating a `BinaryFileResponse` as mentioned in a previous answer:

```
public function fileAction()
{
    // send the file contents and force the browser to download it
    return $this->file('/path/to/some_file.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

+1 for alexander response.

But if you can't use X-Sendfile, you should use the BinaryFileResponse added in the 2.2:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files

In my project the result is

```
$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($dir .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $zipName);

$d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $zipName
   );

$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't have the option of setting headers:

The `download` attribute may help depending on which browsers you need to support:

`<a href="{file url}" download>`

or

`<a href="{file url}" download="{a different file name}">`

This is not supported in all legacy browsers. See this page for browser support:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp