# Symfony2 forcing jpg download returns corrupted file

Tags: symfony, download, jpeg, byte-order-mark, corrupt

Following some of the many posts related to the subject I finally came up with this version of the "force download" code:

```
public function downloadAction(Request $request){

    $filename= 'test.jpg';
    $response = new Response();

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type','image/jpg');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');        

    $response->sendHeaders();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename)); 

    return $response;
}
```

Now, this works fine with zip files (obviously using the right content-type), but for jpg something different happens. When using HexCompare to check both original and downloaded JPG I found that the downloaded version adds "EF BB BF" at the beginning of the file. This seems to be enough for the Windows Image Viewer, which ends reporting a corrupt file error.

On the other hand, the same downloaded jpg opens perfectly in Adobe Photoshop (less strict perhaps?)

Ideas? anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Z

UPDATE: Downloaded Zip files using this code can only be opened with WinRAR or WinZIP, Windows Explorer Zip Extract shows a Corrupt File Error message.

UPDATE2: OK, I know now is a BOM issue. Now, how can I get rid of that nasty "EF BB BF" from the file_get_content result?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010411/symfony2-force-file-download)

```
// Set headers
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));

// Send headers before outputting anything
$response->sendHeaders();
$response->setContent(readfile($filename));
```

If you're using apache with mod_xsendfile, try:

```
return new Response('', 200, array(
    'X-Sendfile'          => $filename,
    'Content-type'        => 'application/octect-stream',
    'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename)),
     // ...
));
```

If you're using nginx's X-Accel read [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile). and use

```
return new Response('', 200, array(
    'X-Accel-Redirect'    => $filename,
    'Content-type'        => 'application/octect-stream',
    'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename)),
    // ...
));
```

to gain more control with nginx additional available options are ...

```
// ...
'X-Accel-Limit-Rate' => '1024',
'X-Accel-Buffering'  => 'yes',  // yes|no
'X-Accel-Charset'    => 'utf-8',
 // ...
```

Comment: Not working nifr. Using this approach the downloaded file gets a couple of hundreds KB bigger, still corrupted output, even for Photoshop. The file downloaded with the original code opens correctly in Photoshop.

Comment: Note: the original testing jpg file is only 633KB which opens fine in Windows 7 Image Viewer. Done some testing on 11KB 1x1pix file, same result.

Comment: Actually nifr, THAT was the first code I used. Took it from that exact post. Exact same result. Keeps adding "EF BB BF" at the beginning of the downloaded file. ...making me crazy.

Comment: have you tried xsendfile / x-accel ? its better anyways because the file is directly served by your webserver. or is this not an option? did you check your code for invisible characters and correct utf-8 encoding?

Comment: not an option, and can't get my hands on the apache. UTF-8 encoding is correct, same for not printable characters check. Keep testing with other file formats and sizes, same result. The "EF BB BF" difference. Code can't get any simpler, right?

Comment: OK, I know now is a BOM issue. Now, how can I get rid of that nasty "EF BB BF" from the file_get_content result?

Comment: have you checked that none of your php files is UTF-8 with BOM ?

Comment: try sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.php if you're on linux. what operating system and which IDE/editor are you using?

Comment: do you have cygwin available to use sed ? otherwise find another way to make sure there is no php file with BOM and try again. clear your cache afterwards please.

Comment: thxs nifr, I don't have it but I'll download it and give it a try. Nothing else seems to work anyways :) Just checked randomly some of the php files without luck, no BOM. Netbeans project is set to UTF-8 but I believe this is not related with the famous BOM chunk. I mean, BOM doesn't determines the UTF-8 encoding, right? and my site charset needs to be UTF-8, of that I'm sure. My question then: if after using sed I can't find any PHP files with BOM headers (my guess), then who could be BOM-tagging the response payload? apache?

Comment: apache might be an option. have you already inspected the response headers? maybe there's something wrong in there. check if all headers are existant.

Comment: echoing the response shows this: HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg Date: Thu, 23 May 2013 22:17:28 GMT ����NExifMM....etc,etc,etc...

Comment: note: echoing directly the result of file_get_contents($filename), without the headers, also reveals the BOM chunk at the beginning of the file: ����NExifMM .converted to ISO 8859 translates to: ï»¿ÿØÿáNExifMM

Comment: Since the question is no longer related with the solution, I decided to start a new, more specific one, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737018/

Comment: Hm you might well accept my answer though as it solves the issue if users use the X-Accel or XSendfile extensions ( because then  symfony is no more involved in serving the file headers and output i guess)