# Symfony2 Remove UTF-8 BOM from controller responses

Tags: symfony, httpresponse, byte-order-mark

While creating a "force download" action I discovered that ALL responses generated by the controller are including the UTF-8 BOM (ï»¿). This is not relevant for regular pages, but for downloaded files is undesirable, since JPG or ZIP are reported as corrupt for several Windows viewing softwares. So, the main goal is to remove the BOM from controller output.

Until now I've done this:

1-Use Win Grep to search for BOM chunk on every file on my site. Zero results.

2-Create a non-symfony test.php on the same web server and check output on the client. No BOM there.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Z

UPDATE: Test Code 1. The resulting JPG includes the BOM.

```
public function downloadAction(Request $request){
    $filename= 'test.jpg';
    $response = new Response(file_get_contents($filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type',mime_content_type($filename));        
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
   return $response;
```

}

Test Code 2. The resulting page also includes the BOM.

```
public function downloadAction(Request $request){
echo 'hello world.';
exit;
```

}

UPDATE2: I just tried this: create a brand new symfony2 project from scratch, added a test controller/action using same IDE, and guess what: NO BOM..so, my guess is that something inside my symfony site is intercepting the response and adding the BOM chunk.

Comment: Can you show us the action code?

Comment: Updated the answer to include both testing codes.

Comment: I provided several solution proposals ( aka finding BOM chunks, removing ) in this answer .. yesterday. just wanted to check back there and... sadly the question author removed the question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719271/symfony2-forcing-jpg-download-returns-corrupted-file/16719624?noredirect=1#comment24081085_16719624

Comment: Errrr...sorry nifr, that would be me. Decided to take out that post since the question it was not longer reflecting the actual problem. Not sure about the right call here, think I'll link it back here. Problem still remains. Thanks a lot for your yesterday contributions.

Comment: as this seems to be a very simple hello-world application can you upload the project ( or the involved parts ) so i can check if the BOM issue occures with my setup ( and search for BOM in files with my tools ) ? I can also test if the bom is included here aswell for Xsendfile and X-Accel solving the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. Believe me I would like to. Anyways, is not a very simple hello-world, I just replace the actual "force download" code with the hello-word eco, in order to simplify the analysis. It is actually a very large real-life project, now trying (unsuccessfully) to include the download functionality.

Comment: Hi nifr. The Win Grep is doing a great job detecting the affected files. I tested other sites with "BOMMED" files, and even simulate my own BOMMED PHP file to verify it was actually working. The thing is that this particular site we are talking about is 100% BOM-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The famous UTF-8 BOM had been added by LocalizeRoute.php twig extension under PEAR. In my particular case it seams Symfony filters all responses through this file, adding the BOM chunk to every page been delivered. Removing the BOM from LocalizeRoute.php was enough to fix the problem. Credits to nifr for suggesting the BOM-search. Used free window's tool WinGrep to run the binary search through the whole server. Thanks a lot.