# Return image from controller in symfoy2

Tags: symfony, http-headers, imagesource

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409115/return-image-from-controller-symfony2) but it doesnt work for me.

my controller looks like:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/testing")
 */
public function trackingNewsletter() {
    $filename =    'T:\wamp\www\trendytouristmx\web\uploads\establishments\1-37.jpg';

    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 
                            'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));
    $response->sendHeaders();

    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));

    return $response;
}
```

But in the browser code is displayed instead of the image displayed:

[browser looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59zR6.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at your headers and share them here.
Look at your wamp log too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special class which is designed for `binary file response`. I would recommend to use it instead. More info [BinaryFileResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html)

```
    //$filePath = ...
    //$filename = ...
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);
    $response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
        $filename,
        iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $filename)
    );

    return $response;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do :

```
public function trackingNewsletter() {
    $path = 'T:\wamp\www\trendytouristmx\web\uploads\establishments\1-37.jpg';
    $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($path));
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($path));
    $response->sendHeaders();
    $response->setContent(readfile($path));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you **@chalasr**, finally it works, here's a solution:

- first, I removed `$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');`
- second, I changed the value of `Content-Disposition` from `attachment` to `inline`.

---

```
/**
 * @Route("/tracking")
 */
public function trackingnewsletterAction() {
    $filename =    '...\establishments\1-39.jpg';
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 
    'inline; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));
    $response->sendHeaders();

    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: No problem, I've accidentally deleted my answer. I have re-added it, but  you can accept yours.