# How to download a file from view in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, download, http-status-code-404, twig

I have a app made with Symfony2 and in my twig template, I show a table with some pdf files.

This pdf files (one for user) are stored in `/app/var/pdf/xxx.pdf`.

If I use:

```
<a href="{{ 'entity.pdf' }}">PDF</a>
```

My path is correct, for example: `symfony/app/var/pdf/123123.pdf`, but when I click in the link, my browser return a 404 Not Found error. Obviusly I have checked that the file is stored in this path.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To force download the pdf file try this in the controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/download/{id}",name="pdf_download")
 */
public function downloadAction($id) {


    $downloadedFile = $repository->findOneBy(
            array(
                'id' => $id,
            )
    );
    $response=new Response();


    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"',          $downloadedFile->getFilename() ));
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($downloadedFile->getAbsolutePath()));
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires', '0');
    return $response;

 }
```

And in the  template

```
  <a href={{path('pdf_download',{'id':file.id})}}>{{file.filename}}</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You better need to store this file in public `web` dir, and then create link to it like:

```
<a href="{{ asset('web/var/pdf/xxx.pdf') }}"/>PDF</a>
```

But browsers open `pdf` files in new tab. And if you really want to force dowload of this file, need to use headers. Use this question for help [Symfony2 - Force file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010411/symfony2-force-file-download)

Comment: thanks, but the error is the same, error 404, and if is possible, I prefer don't use assetics

Comment: Do you really create `web/var/pdf` directory and copy `xxx.pdf` to it? Try it with `asset` first, please.

Comment: yes, and I put 777 permisions, but the error 404 persist

Comment: If it's not work, maybe you intercept access to file with `.htaccess`. Also check code of `.htaccess` in root and `web` dir, please

Comment: I have checked it but .htaccess doesn't intercept anything of this dir.

Comment: Do you can show me your root dir structure and URL address of site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute URL like below

```
<a href="{{ absolute_url(asset('uploads/YOURPATCH/'))}}pdf_download" download>
 Download 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :

```
<a download href="{{ asset('/images/CV.pdf') }}" >Télécharger mon CV <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```