# symfony - download files

Tags: php, symfony, header, download

I am trying download files in controller but in the console I see only really bunch of weird characters instead of download box. I am following this topic [Symfony2 - Force file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010411/symfony2-force-file-download).

Don't know what is going on... trying to find simplest solution. 
Here is my code:

```
 $response = new Response(file_get_contents($file->realPath), 200, array(
            'Content-Type' => $file->mimeType,
            'Content-Length' => filesize($file->realPath),
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $file->name,
        ));
 $response->send();
```

I've even tried to use the most basic example with header() and readfile().
Does my server need special config or something? Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of rebuilding that kind of response, you could use Symfony's built-in`BinaryFileResponse`.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

$response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);
```

Please take also a look in the [documentation about serving files](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files).

Answer (score 4):

In the controller you can use `$this->file(...)`

The file needs full filesystem path with file to download

```
return $this->file('/home/website/upload/'.$someFile)
```

Also it is possible to define another name when downloading:

```
return $this->file('/home/website/upload/'.$someFile, 'MyFile.pdf');
```

Comment: True, but this solution requires to `extends AbstractController` or using the `ControllerTrait`. This is not always the case as some prefer to decouple controllers from the framework entirely.