# Symfony - Custom API - Force download

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, symfony-2.7

On my Symfony 2.7 website I created a custom Bundle to make a simple API. I don't use any vendors and all the codes are developed from scratch (it's a small REST API, for a very limited and private scope of users/friends).

In my controller I send Json responses if some of the functions and tests failed :

```
if ( !all_is_ok() )
{
    return new JsonResponse(" [...] JSON array with error details [...] ");
}
else
{
    // Force download of a specific file
}
```

How to force download in the "else" statement of the code above ?
Do i have to use the Response component ?

**P.S : the client of this API is a PHP script with a curl() call. How to manage file download in such specific case ? Do I have to output the URL link in JSON ?**

in fact I've already tested BinaryFileResponse but result is not what I expected. If I make a CURL call with the POST method (CURLOPT_POST = 1), result is : Error: "" - Code: 0

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603052/symfony-download-files

Comment: @Tokeeen.com, in fact I've already tested BinaryFileResponse but result is not what I expected. If trying to make a CURL call with the POST method (CURLOPT_POST = 1), result is : Error: "" - Code: 0