# Download a file in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to download the current html page as a file in symfony :

**My twig :**

```
<a href="{{ path('polytech_skills_evaluations_export', {'idssoccasion': ssoccasion.id, 'idevalue':user.id}) }}" >Exporter </a>
```

**My Controller**

```
 $html= $this->renderView('PolytechSkillsBundle:Evaluation/Evaluation:type2.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'niveaux' => $niveaux,
        'date' => $dateCourante,
        'evalue' => $evalue,
        'ssoccasion' => $ssoccasion,
        'lasteval' => $lastEval,
        'lastevalforocc' => $lastEvalForOccasion,
        'objectifs' => $objectifs
    ));

    $response = new Response();
    // Set headers
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($html));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($html) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($html));
    // Send headers before outputting anything
    $response->sendHeaders();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($html));
```

**The error I get :**

```
Warning: mime_content_type failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010411/symfony2-force-file-download

Comment: I read the suggested solutions and this is what I used but I think it connot consider $ html as a file

Comment: the error become : The file "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Polytech Skills</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/bundles/polytechskills/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> ..... does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in this case is to save (even temporarily the page) then force the download :

```
file_put_contents('page.html', $content);
```

You can then download the file with a code like this :

```
// Create response et hydrate headers
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(file_get_contents('page.html'));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
$response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'filename=page.html');

// Return response
return $response;
```

Polytech school :) ?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Perfect ! I am a alumnus Polytech student;)
Do not forget to indicate that the solution worked by a +1 or validation to help the community. Thank you.

Comment: I did'nt get it ! how can i indicate that ?