# Symfony: Force file download encoding not working

Tags: php, file, symfony, csv

I have created a function in my symfony project that force download a CSV file when click on button based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025363/1749653). The thing is the download works just fine, but the encoding of the file seems to be wrong.
The frensh caracters `'` , `é` , `à` and `è` turn into `‚Äô`, `√©` ...

my function:

```
/**
 * exportNewsAction
 *
 * @Route("/getNewsSections", name="newsitem_getNewsSections", options = { "expose" = true })
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function exportNewsAction() {
    $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/Resources/files/csvExport';
    $csvPath = $path."/News-Item-".$now.".csv";
    $response = new Response();
    $f = fopen($csvPath, "w");
    $titleArray=array('Id', 'Nom', 'Prénom', 'Profile', 'Status', 'Date de création');
    fputcsv($f, $titleArray);

    // Set headers
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($csvPath));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($csvPath) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($csvPath));

    // Send headers before outputting anything
    $response->sendHeaders();

    return $response->setContent(file_get_contents($csvPath));
}
```

What should I change to get the exact same worlds I used? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is mime_content_type($csvPath) returning what you're expecting it to return?  Also, where are you setting the character encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force download a file and preserve its original contents, it's better to use `BinaryFileResponse` instead of the regular `Response`. It's doing everything that you're doing manually in your code, and then some. Your controller code can look just like this:

```
public function exportNewsAction() {
    $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/Resources/files/csvExport';
    $csvPath = $path."/News-Item-".$now.".csv";
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($csvPath);
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        basename($csvPath)
    );

    return $response;
}
```

Also, how are you opening the downloaded CSV? If you're using MS Excel, there's a big chance that it won't detect the encoding properly. Try opening the file with some text editor, like Notepad++, see how the characters look like and which encoding it detects.

Comment: The "return new BinaryFileResponse($csvPath);" didn't force download the file. I'm using Libre office to open the CSV file.

Comment: Edited my answer, this should force the download now. Try opening the file with some text editor, like Notepad++, see how the characters look like and which encoding it detects.

Comment: Turned out the problem is with the LibreOffice application. The characters are fine when i open with a text editor.

Comment: Would you please add that hint to your answer so I can approve it?

Comment: Done. By the way, did using `BinaryFileResponse` work as well? I believe you should use it, so that you can take advantage of a tried tool provided by the framework instead of repeating the work yourself.